# Express changes string on POST request

Tags: node.js, express, encoding, character-encoding

I'm attaching user info (got by authorization header) with each request (post/put/get/delete) to request headers

```js
...
req.headers.user = {
   phone: "+37066666666",
   id: "bda5a3c0-2e95-4d6d-bf1f-6c1c8f1edcaa"
};
...
```

and I have `POST` request sent by POSTMAN (for example) where I'm sending this body as JSON object:

```js
{
    "title": "test",
    "users": [
        {
            "phone": "+37066666666"
        }
    ]
}
```

where later my code checks if there are owner in this users array and it should append owner if not. but I can't do that since user object that was set in headers have different phone number than phone number of the first user in the `users` object. Even the number is the same.

So I printed the number stored in headers and the one sent with `POST` request and this is what I saw:

the number stored in headers after utf=8 decode method: `\x2B\x33\x37\x30\x36\x35\x31\x35\x36\x35\x39\x30\xE2\x80\xAC\xE2\x80\xAC\xE2\x80\xAC`

and the number sent with `POST` request:
`\x2B\x33\x37\x30\x36\x35\x31\x35\x36\x35\x39\x30`

so how this can be fixed? apparently my method to find user doesn't work since the numbers "are not the same"

```js
req.body.users.find(v => v.phone === req.headers.user.phone)
```

this method will return "undefined" even the printed `v.phone` and `req.headers.user.phone` values are the same (on console).

Answer (score 1):

the problem was my macbook "paste" function. it was pasting invisible characters:

```js
"users": [
        {
            "phone": "+370...<202c><202c>",
            ...
        }
```